# How to send data to another page without using cookies or JS in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, privacy

So, I have a PHP file that runs an SQL(MySql) query and gets the result. I need that page to send that result to another page automatically(I can use PHP in the receiving page). However, I want to make my website accessible to privacy-sensitive people who disable cookies and javascript on their browsers. I'm not using any PHP frameworks.

An initial page that runs the query only runs in the backend like a controller so it does not have any HTML in it. This means I cannot use a hidden form and make the user submit it with a button. I thought about sessions but they need cookies to work and JSON needs javascript. I thought about sending the data in the URL but the query result is quite big and I was afraid it could exceed some kind of URL length limits(if such thing exists). Is there a way to achieve this reliably?

EDIT: To clarify some things, the data I am sending is a search result so the query changes depending on the users input(which was provided to the page which runs the query with a form).

Comment: GET, POST Methods?

Comment: If it’s just search terms, I’d go with URL params. That’s how us old timers used to do this before cookies were invented . You can reliably pass up to about 4K in the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store data somewhere and send id or something through  query string and access data from database through that id from query string. Sending too much data is not advisable through cookies, session or even query string just pass your unique id and grab data from db.
Happy coding.

Comment: So are you suggesting me to store the results of my query to temporally the database somehow and send an id through the url?

Comment: Yes Sir or store at local storage